# Moderators Pro Tempore, just like mamma used to make 'em

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that the following members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that the community's issues are properly addressed.

[image: Rarity]
[image: jcmeloni]
[image: NickC]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections after your site makes it through graduation.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It's a learning experience for everyone.

---

Unfortunately both Rarity and jcmeloni have asked to step down. Moderation is a purely volunteer activity and we are very grateful for the time and effort they both donated to the site.

We have two new volunteers who graciously agreed to step up and help moderate:

[image: jmort253]
[image: Jim]

Thanks, jmort253 and Jim!

Answer (score 14):

**Congratulations Julie, Ben, Nick and James!**

All of the nominees are exemplary contributors and would make excellent moderators, I'm sure the choice was more than tough for everyone involved. But let's not forget that all of us can and should do our part in moderating the site, and our three diamonds are mostly exception handlers, it's up to all of us to keep the site healthy and help it grow to a wonderful resource.

Some light reading to get you started:

- [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)
- [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet)

And if you haven't already, start using [Pro-forma comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) immediately, it's a life saver ;)

Comment: Thanks! This will be fun (and useful to THE WORLD and so on)...