# Election page not found

Tags: support, status-bydesign, moderators

I was not sure how to inform everyone, but obviously there has not been any elections but also there is not an election page to tell me when there will be elections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beta sites do not have moderator elections, [moderators are appointed by Stack Exchange](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/moderators-pro-tempore-just-like-mamma-used-to-make-em).

The Workplace will have its first election shortly after graduation, but right now we don't know when that is, thus we have no idea when the election will be.

Comment: Tomorrow!       ?[[[[[]]]]]