# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The Workplace's [1st moderator election](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: jmort253] [image: Monica Cellio] [image: jmac]

They'll be taking over for [the existing crew](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Be sure to give a hearty "Thank you!" to [the Moderators Pro Tempore](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/moderators-pro-tempore-just-like-mamma-used-to-make-em) who served this community during the beta: [Rarity](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/42/rarity), [jcmeloni](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/26/jcmeloni), [nickc](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/17/nickc), [jmort253](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/98/jmort253) and [Jim](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/869/jim).

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6018905831112704/0).

Comment: Congrats to you all! Thanks again to Jim and NickC for their contributions up until now, hopefully we will still see you both active around here as regular users

Comment: I add my congratulations.  Well done and good luck!

Comment: @NickC - They already took your diamond :( Thanks for everything you did here.

Comment: @NickC: Thanks, man. Good luck with everything.

Comment: Congratulations! Now don't just sit there - go and moderate! ;-)

Comment: Congratulations!