# Recent Changes to The Workplace

Tags: support, faq

This is an unofficial list of various changes to The Workplace, modeled after [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

To see the list in reverse chronological order (latest entry on top), **[sort Answers by latest activity first](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2570/recent-changes-to-the-workplace?answertab=active#tab-top)**.

Comment: I updated the list with some recent changes. To be notified when issues are updated, please star this question.

Answer (score 6):

#### August 2014

- 2014-08-27: [Comments without upvotes are now hidden if a question has more than two answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2899/168).
- 2014-08-19: The [2nd 2014 Summer Moderator Election](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2874/98) results are in. [enderland](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/2322) wins the election and joins the moderation team.
- 2014-08-12: Stack Exchange releases network-wide feature that [allow moderators to move some comments to a chat room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237976/155826).
- 2014-08-04 The [2nd 2014 Summer Moderator Election](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/summer-2014-community-moderator-election) begins.

#### July 2014

- 2014-07-23: Moderator [jmac](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/7945) leaves the moderation team and [joins Stack Exchange as a community manager](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/07/please-welcome-jmac-community-manager-of-the-rising-sun/).

#### April 2014

- 2014-04-13: The [About Page/Tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) has been updated
- 2014-04-13: This document was created
- 2014-04-08: [2014 Community Election](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/2014-community-moderator-election-results) completed, [jmort253](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/98), [Monica Cellio](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/325), and [jmac](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/7945) elected moderators

#### February 2014

- 2014-02-20: site graduation - [New Design Launched](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/new-design-launched)

#### January 2014

- 2014-01-21: trusted users at TWP can protect questions [without having to wait 24 hours](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3060?m=13304581#13304581)

Answer (score 4):

#### January 2013

- 2013-01-19: [community wiki threshold set to 15 answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1659/168)

Answer (score 3):

#### August 2015

- 2015-08-03: [Chinese characters are now blocked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23180700#23180700) in posts on The Workplace, both titles and bodies of posts. This was done to prevent [spammers attacks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnkMk.png).