# Summer 2014 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

It's that time again... One of the moderators on The Workplace recently became [an SE employee](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/07/please-welcome-jmac-community-manager-of-the-rising-sun/). Now, the community needs to elect a new moderator on TWP to fill their shoes.

**The 2014 Community Moderator Election is now underway!**

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: @Shog9 = No we had him first you cant have him!  Congrats jmac unless this comment cost you the job then oops.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame, thanks! There's a blog post -- if that isn't a legally binding contract, I just don't know what is. Whoever gets the mod position on TWP gets to haggle with Shog over our return policy if they do decide to get rid of me. Just be sure to point out that we do not warrant against latent defects!