# Summer 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

The Workplace's [2nd moderator election](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: enderland]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6066715192459264/0).

Answer (score 17):

Thanks everyone, looking forward to helping out!

Hopefully everyone who voted or ran continues to be excited about the site.

Comment: Congratulations, @enderland. Looking forward to working with you to keep making The Workplace SE awesome! :)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere thanks for being a great contributor here! I sure find myself upvoting a lot of your answers... :)

Comment: Congratulations @enderland

Comment: Congrats enderland!

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations enderland! We look forward to your great support as we continue our Workplace adventure.

Comment: Thanks! It's fun for me to see new faces get involved here too, so definitely keep up the good work. The Workplace has been a lot of fun and beneficial both personally and professionally for me for quite some time now :)

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations enderland!  I am glad that it was you.